# Get table data from mysqli from a certain date

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm writing a script that gets data from a data base and displays it. I need it to
only display data from a certain date on each page, the date defined by a html input form. Take a look at the code.

```
     }else{
        //date selector - this chooses which date to display the data. The output of this needs to
    be what date the data is sorted by.
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        echo "
        <input type='date' name='date' value='$date'>";
        //include the database connection so you can fetch data from the table 'notices'
        include("db.php");
        //sql fetching data from the database ad displaying it
//Each row of data is currently sorted by the field id, which is currently auto-incrementing
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM notices ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "
                <p><b>".$row['subject']."</b></p>
                <p>".$row['message']."</p>
                <p>".$row['name']."<br></p>
                <hr>
                ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use date parameter in where clause

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli query to display data from database a simple code like this

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT date FROM database where date = your html form input date")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: OP is using PDO here, and not the MySQLi_ API.